Call legacy web service when migrating Xamarin Android app to .NET 8 phone application
I'm migrating my Xamarin Android app to .NET 8 and I'm having issues access my legacy web service(s).  I am able to add the service to the app via Add->Service Reference, but cannot instantiate a reference to the service in code.  My old code is:
MyService.Manager myService = new MyService.Manager.Manager();

I have access to all the methods and data, no problems.  In my new code, when I enter the URL to the Service and click go, I get the service name with the word "Soap" added to it.  When I select ManagerSoap all the methods are there in the operations list, so I'm obviously gotten to the correct place.  I change the service name from ServiceReference1 to MyService so it'll match my code so I won't have to re-code all my references.  When I attempt to instantiate the reference I see that name has changed to MyService.ManagerSoapClient, but when I type the code:
MyService.ManagerSoapClient myService = new MyService.ManagerSoapClient();

I get the intellisense error "MyService.ManagerSoapClient does not contain a constructor that contains 0 arguments".  Obviously I'm not doing something right but I am unable to figure out what the issue is.  Can anyone help me with this?
